# are whatsapp chats stored in my phone or PC?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need to print my chats with my fiance for her visa but its taking FOREVER to scroll up to the very beginning. is there somewhere whatsapp stores the chats in eithr thre PC or phone that i can just print it?

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp chats are stored on your phone, which can backed up to Google Drive if you enable it. To print conversation you can email the chat conversation. 
To export a copy of the history of an individual chat or group, use the Export chat feature:

Open the chat for the individual or group.

- Tap the Menu Button.
- Tap More.
- Tap Export chat.
- Choose whether to Include Media or not.

An email will be composed with your chat history attached as a .txt document.